# Count of different ways to express N as the sum of 1, 3

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

What is the logical way to approach this problem ?
I found the solution here : [solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-ofdifferent-ways-express-n-sum-1-3-4/) which looks simple to code but I am having  some difficulty understanding it logically.

From the same blog I am not able to understand this line,

> So the number that ends with 1 is equal to DP[n-1].

Is there an easier way in which this solution can be explained?

Answer (score 7):

Assume you are going to express 10 as the sum of 1 and 3.Then you can express 10 as `9+1` or `7+3`. Then number of different ways that 10 can be expressed is equal to sum of number of different ways that 9 and 7 can be expressed.

i.e`dp[10]=dp[9]+dp[7]`

Comment: Perfect explanation!

Answer (score 4):

Just you need to think recursively. Suppose `R(n)` shows the number of ways to write `n` as the sum of 1 and 3s. The last number could be 1 or 3. If the last number is 1, we should count `R(n-1)`, and if the last number is `3` we should count `R(n-3)`. We know that the solution of these approach has not any overlap. Because the end number of each o them is different (one of them is `1` and the other one is `3`).
Therfore, `R(n) = R(n-1) + R(n-3)`.

In addition, to compute `R(n)`, we need three initial values. `R(1) = 1`, `R(2) = 1`, and `R(3) = 2`.

Comment: Good explanation - except your initial values are wrong. R(3)=2, not 1 as you can write 3 in two ways: 3 or 1+1+1.

Comment: why is Base case :
DP[0]  = 1 in the same link shared? in your case R(0)

Comment: @Hussain in my case, you do not need `R(0)`, as initial cases are 1, 2, and 3. So, `n > 3` in my specified recursive function.